# Is there any reason not to include every attribute in the product flat tables ('Used in Product Listing" - Yes)

Tags: performance, product-collection, flat

While building google product feeds, I found it necessary (or at least helpful) to add a few attributes to the product flat table which I normally don't use in my listings.

Is there any reason not to include every attribute in the flat table? Wouldn't it be easier and more flexible? I guess the idea is that it will affect performance? But will it actually have any kind of effect? On a related matter, does including all (available) attributes in product collections have a real effect on performance? Is it much faster to only select the attributes you will use?

Answer (score 1):

You are going down a dangerous path if you are looking to add more and more fields to the flat tables. Flat tables for categories and products are intended to be used on catalog pages only. You should be writing your own collections for creating product feeds and as such.

If all your attributes are not coming from flat tables, including all of them in collections would have impact on performance because you would then be making all the joins behind the scenes between all the eav tables to fetch additional attributes. It would make the operation more DB intensive. So in short - More the eav attributes you are trying to get more DB intensive the task.It is optimal for performance to fetch only the attributes you need.

If you add all attributes to flat tables the time your catalog takes to re-index flat tables would shoot up. This might sound okay with a small catalog with few categories and products but you're looking at trouble if your catalog is to get bigger.